# How to delete a credit card using the USAEPAY Web service?

Tags: java, jax-ws, credit-card

I am using the USAEPAY Web service for credit card services, including adding, updating and deleting credit cards.  Adding/updating works fine, however the credit card deletion results in the error:

**com.usaepay.api.jaxws.GeneralFault_Exception: 40030: Customer Not Found**

It is quite strange because I check the customer number in all other operations and this number  is the same and it works

Code example

Add credit card:

```
public void addPaymentMethodToCustomer(String customerNum, SavedCreditCardInfo savedCreditCardInfo, Address address)  {
    UeSecurityToken securityToken = getSecurityToken(null);
    PaymentMethod paymentMethod = createUSAEPaymentMethod(savedCreditCardInfo, address);
    BigInteger paymentMethodID = null;

    if(securityToken != null) {
        try {
            UeSoapServerPortType client = getClient();
            paymentMethodID = client.addCustomerPaymentMethod(securityToken, new BigInteger(customerNum), paymentMethod, false, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to add payment method for customer " + customerNum, e);
            throw new AddPaymentMethodException("Unable to add payment method for USA E Pay customer num " + customerNum);
        }
        LOG.info("Succesfully added payment method for customer=" + customerNum +  " with payment method=" + paymentMethodID );
    }
}
```

Log:

**INFO  com.smartdestinations.service.payment.impl.USAEPayServiceImpl:288 - Succesfully added payment method for customer=25468380 with payment method=12184**

Deletion:

```
public void deleteCustomerPaymentMethod(String paymentMethodId, String customerNum) {
    UeSecurityToken securityToken = getSecurityToken(null);
    if(securityToken != null) {
        try {
            UeSoapServerPortType client = getClient();
            client.deleteCustomerPaymentMethod(securityToken, new BigInteger(customerNum), new BigInteger(paymentMethodId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to delete payment method with customerNumber=" + customerNum + " and paymentID=" + paymentMethodId, e);
            throw new DeletePaymentMethodException("Unable to delete payment with id " + paymentMethodId + " for customer " + customerNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Log:
**com.smartdestinations.service.payment.impl.USAEPayServiceImpl:388 - Unable to delete payment method with customerNumber=25468380 and paymentID=12184
com.usaepay.api.jaxws.GeneralFault_Exception: 40030: Customer Not Found**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a bug in USAEPAY.  They promised to fix this bug